# computing the average of a metric following a weighting scheme upon a tree structure

Tags: clustering, autocorrelation

I'm clustering objects using a particular metric. I thus obtain a tree structure representing the relatedness of the objects.

I want to compute statistics (e.g., average) on other metrics computed from the same objects.

As I want to account for the relatedness of objects when computing the statistics, I need to implement a weighting scheme that accounts for that particular tree structure and distance. This would result in down-weighting close objects and up-weighting distant objects. How can I do that?

In other words, this is a way for controlling for autocorrelation when computing simple statistics like the average.